# Session cookie versus other kinds of cookies

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

In Internet Explorer, for example, you can enable first party cookies, third party cookies and allow session cookies.

I know the difference between:

- a first party cookie and a third party cookie, and
- a PHP session and a cookie.

But what is a *session cookie*? And how can you set one using PHP?

For example, you cannot log into Facebook without cookies enabled. However, if you allow *session* cookies, you *can* log into Facebook.

So, how does a session cookie differ from other kinds of cookies?

Comment: One place to start is the info page for the [\[session-cookies\]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/session-cookies/info) tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A cookie has a lifetime, after which it will expire (As denoted by the `Expires` directive). If you don't set a timeout, the browser will expire the cookie when you close the browser. This is called a session cookie.

These kind of cookies are often used to track a users current session state on the server side (E.g. php's sessions), but there is not a strong relation between the two uses of the word "session"

Comment: This question also interests me. Do you mean there is nothing special in a cookie itself which identified it as a session cookie? A special keyword or something? (found the answer: a session cookie has no `Expires` -- which means your definition is not fully correct)

Comment: thanks troelskn, that appears to be solving my problems.. regards J... can I ask... do sites like faceobok etc.. use these kind of session cookies rather than php_sessions to keep a user logged in, so that it is less intensive of the server?  regards J

Comment: @jon Server side state mechanisms (Such as php's sessions) are usually tracked through a session cookie. So in these cases, session cookies are used as a foundation for server side sessions. They are not alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

A session cookie holds the unique identifier that PHP generates when `session_start()` is called, so that each client can be associated with a session, and no two sessions can have the same ID *at the same time*.

The session cookie is usually destroyed when the browser window is closed, or can be done manually using `session_destroy()`.

Comment: I think the question is in context to the how the browser identifies the cookie. Note the IE references.

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_cookie#Session_cookie):

**Older definition:** *(2011-12-17)*

> A session cookie is created when no Expires directive is provided when
>   the cookie is created.

**Latest definition:**

> A *session cookie*, also known as an *in-memory cookie* or *transient
>   cookie*, exists only in temporary memory while the user navigates the
>   website.<sup>[[18]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#cite_note-mscookie-18)</sup> Web browsers normally delete session cookies when the
>   user closes the browser.<sup>[[19]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#cite_note-19)</sup> Unlike other cookies, session cookies do
>   not have an expiration date assigned to them, which is how the browser
>   knows to treat them as session cookies.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, when you use `session_start()` it creates a session, this will create a session cookie in the client browser, PHP needs the client to send this info back with each request so that PHP can tell the session ID.

Comment: Im not saying you are wrong, however I can still use php sessions and have 1st party cookies disabled and dont allow session cookies... so Im assuming that sessions are stored purely server-side?... regards J

Comment: @jon: The actual session is stored server-side, but there is a reference to the session on the client side.

Comment: Thanks Richard... that is because without the cookie, you would'nt know what session was for what user.