# Why Chrome Developer Tools Shows a Cookie Expiration to Session?

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome

I am using ASP.NET Session and Form Authentication. I have set the Timeout of their cookie. But Chrome Showing me that Cookie Expiration is equal to Session,

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code that you're using to set the expiration?

Comment: @tristankoffee, Here is the forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="XX"

Comment: I think I got this. The issue is that ASP.NET does not set the cookie expiration of these cookies because they are not persistent. So that's why they are called Session Cookies.

Comment: Your comment is correct. Whenever you don't set an expiry date then it means you want a non-persistent cookie, therefore a "session cookie" will becreated. It typically exists in memory of the browser (not in physical storage such as file or DB). Whenever the browser's process is closed those cookies are deleted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Session cookie versus other kinds of cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547620/session-cookie-versus-other-kinds-of-cookies)